# connect to a database from a prestashop module

Tags: mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

the module can't connect with the database.

I have a prestashop module that has to do a task with a database when this hook is launched: hookActionPaymentConfirmation. But I can't do anything, I don't know if it's a problem with the connection or with the query. This is the code of the function of the hookActionPaymentConfirmation, do you see any error? The task is to update the stock of products in a table of the same database. I want to do it with the name of the database and the name of the server, because I'm planning to implement that table in an external database.

```
`    public function hookActionPaymentConfirmation($params)
    {
        //mail("luilli.guillan@gmail.com", "yiha", "hola");
        $database=Configuration::get('MIMODULOMISMADB_ACCOUNT_NOMBREDB', null);
        $user=Configuration::get('MIMODULOMISMADB_ACCOUNT_USUARIO', null);
        $password=Configuration::get('MIMODULOMISMADB_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD', null);
        //
        $db = new DbMySQLi("localhost",$user,$password,$database,true);
        
        //$products = $params['cart']->getProducts(true);//en los nuevos ps ya no va y hay que hacerlo con las dos ordenes siguientes
        $order = new Order($params['id_order']);
    $products = $order->getCartProducts();
    
        foreach ($products as $product) 
        {
            $id_product = $product['id_product'];
            $cantidad = $product['cart_quantity'];
            $referencia = $product['reference'];
            $product_attribute_id = $product['product_attribute_id'];
            
            $newProduct = new Product($id_product);
            if($newProduct->hasCombinations())
            {
                $sql = 'select * from product_attribute where id_product_attribute = ' . (string) $product_attribute_id . ';';
                //$rec = DB::getInstance()->getRow($sql);
                $rec = $db->getValue($sql);
                $referencia = $rec["reference"];
                //mail("luilli.guillan@gmail.com", "has combinations", $id_product." ".$referencia." ".$cantidad." p.a: ".$product_attribute);
            }
            
            $unidades = $db->getValue('SELECT unidades FROM productos WHERE '.$campoid.' = "'.$referencia.'"');         
            $unidadesRestantes=$unidades-$cantidad;
            $db->Execute('UPDATE productos SET unidades="'.$unidadesRestantes.'" WHERE '.$campoid.' = "'.$referencia.'"');          
            mail("luilli.guillan@gmail.com", "yay",$database." ".$user." ".$password." ".$unidades);
            //mail("luilli.guillan@gmail.com", "yay",$unidades);                        
    }   
    }`
```

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: no, i don't get any error.

Comment: Did you enabled debug mode?

Answer (score 0):

i've already solved.It was this line missing:  `$campoid = Configuration::get('CAMPOID', null);`
This is the complete code of the hook:

```
public function hookActionPaymentConfirmation($params) {
    
    
    
    $database = Configuration::get('MIMODULOMISMADB_ACCOUNT_NOMBREDB', null);
    $user = Configuration::get('MIMODULOMISMADB_ACCOUNT_USUARIO', null);
    $password = Configuration::get('MIMODULOMISMADB_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD', null);
    $campoid = Configuration::get('CAMPOID', null);

    $order = new Order($params['id_order']);
    $products = $order->getCartProducts();
    
try {
        $db = new DbMySQLi("localhost", $user, $password, $database, true);
    } catch (PrestaShopDatabaseException $ex) {
    
        $dbLocal = \Db::getInstance();
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $cantidad = $product['cart_quantity'];
            $referencia = $product['reference'];
            $dbLocal->Execute("insert into bufferQuerys (referencia,unidadesCompradas) values('" . $referencia . "','" . $cantidad . "')");
           
            
        }
        
    }
    
    
    if ($db) 
    {
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $id_product = $product['id_product'];
            $cantidad = $product['cart_quantity'];
            $referencia = $product['reference'];
            $product_attribute_id = $product['product_attribute_id'];

            $newProduct = new Product($id_product);
            if ($newProduct->hasCombinations()) {
                $sql = 'select * from product_attribute where id_product_attribute = ' . (string) $product_attribute_id . ';';
                $rec = DB::getInstance()->getRow($sql);
                //$rec = $db->getValue($sql);
                $referencia = $rec["reference"];
                
            }

            $unidades = $db->getValue('SELECT unidades FROM productos WHERE ' . $campoid . ' = "' . $referencia . '"');
            $unidadesRestantes = $unidades - $cantidad;
            $db->Execute('UPDATE productos SET unidades="' . $unidadesRestantes . '" WHERE ' . $campoid . ' = "' . $referencia . '"');
            
        }
    } 
   
}
```

the variable `campoid` is used in this statement: `$db->Execute('UPDATE productos SET unidades="' . $unidadesRestantes . '" WHERE ' . $campoid . ' = "' . $referencia . '"');` but it was not defined.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).